# How to import big mailboxes with low RAM

Tags: migration, zimbra

I'm having problems to import tgz compressed mailboxes (800 MB - 4GB). I have a machine with 8GB of RAM.

always when i try to import with `zmmailbox -z -m user@domain pru "//?fmt=tgz" mailbox.tgz` the service zmmailboxd is stopped.

Any advice?